# How to display some text besides mouse pointer when the mouse hover over QGraphicsItem's in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a QGraphicsView, which contains many rectangle and polylines. I wanted to print every object names ( every rectangle, polylines have names) once I clicked them on view through mouse click. I did that and worked perfectly.
But now I want to do that over mouse hovering. It means, if I hover a mouse over particular object, it should show its name besides cursor.
I tried that, but

```
 I am not understanding, on hovering, how that particular object should get selected ?       
 And how to print its name besides cursor point ?
```

I tried this way:

```
bool myClass::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    bool filterEvent = false;
    switch(event->type())
    {
        case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
        {....}
        case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
        {...}
        case QEvent::Enter:
        {
           QMouseEvent * mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
           QPointF po = _view->mapToScene(mouseEvent->pos());
           FindNamesOverHover(po);
        }
          return true;

       default:
           break;
    }
    return filterEvent;
}       
      
void myClass::FindNamesOverHover(QPointF p)
{
    QGraphicsRectItem* rItem = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsRectItem*>(_scene->itemAt(p,QTransform()));
    if(rItem)
    {
      // some logic 
         qDebug()<< "Instance name is " << i->Name();
    }
    
}
```

Constructor of class myClass

```
myClass::myClass(QWidget* parent) :
    QDockWidget(parent)
{
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    view->setScene(_scene);     
    view->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
}
```

Now above code works only,

```
When I select object through mouse click and then again hover over it.
Then it prints its name on console.
```

But I want only hovering ( no selection through mouse click) will show its name besides cursor point.
Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override `QGraphicsScene.mouseMoveEvent` and inside it use `QGraphicsScene.itemAt` to query for item under cursor. To display you can use  `QGraphicsTextItem`, just move it to correct position and apply text.

Comment: Sorry but it is not working.

Comment: What exactly not working, you dont capture mouse events?

Comment: I have updated the code. First look into it. I debugged and found that, `mouseEvent->pos()` is giving wrong points. That's why `itemAt()` is not selecting any `QGraphicsItem`. Manually I gave correct point to `itemAt()` and I got correct output. Why `mouseEvent->pos()` is not giving correct point ?

Comment: The `mouseEvent->pos()` point is showing `QPointF(449,1562)` but actual point is `QPoint(295,77)`

Comment: QEvent::Enter happens when your mouse enters viewport (crosses it's border), it's probably not what you intent.

Comment: I dont want that. I want mouse hovering over item. I tried your approach but it is not entering in the MouseMoveEvent(). I checked by applying some `qDebug()`

Comment: Did you try it by using eventFilter or by subclassing QGraphicsScene?

Comment: I observed while overriding `mouseMoveEvent` that I override it from `QWidget` . I did not get QGraphicsScene as you mentioned.  I tried like, mouseRightClick -> Refactor-> and then search mouseMoveEvent.